# AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'dataset'

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

[Issue shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TOYC.png)

## Original issue:

```
ERROR:
2021-01-27T11:39:28.243;152721ms;ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3;ERROR;__main__;Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "data_cache_main.py", line 295, in process_batch
      File "utils.py", line 155, in f_retry
      File "data_cache_main.py", line 129, in data_merge
      File "pandas\io\parquet.py", line 317, in read_parquet
      File "pandas\io\parquet.py", line 142, in read
      File "pyarrow\parquet.py", line 1680, in read_table
      File "pyarrow\parquet.py", line 1456, in __init__
    AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'dataset'
```

CodeLine in my script:
[CodeLine in my script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYLYl.png)

CodeLine in the package:
[CodeLine in the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm0KE.png)

I knew the hidden import will have this kind of issue during packing to exe, so I applied the solution I used in my pre-project. but another issue -'No module named 'pyarrow._csv'' happened if put the "import pyarrow.dataset as ds" at the beginning in my main script to make the import without hide as below screenshot. Eventually, I started to think it may not be the same issue as I met before. (Since then I added retry, it did help but cannot fix the issue )

[my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSFLo.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Espc. do not post screen-shots of code.

Comment: In addition, you will need to provide more details on what system is running, how did you install pyarrow, ... You mention something about "packing to exe" ?